# Creating a Springboot Web Service SOAP client

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot

I am creating a simple Springboot application (1.5.2) with a dependency on `springboot-starter-web-services`.

I have the WSDL for the service I need to consume and have generated all of the classes by using wsimport. One thing I noticed was the generated classes includes an interface with all of the remote methods & their annotations.

My question, *should I be using this interface? If so, how do I configure spring to use it?*

I followed the [Springboot tutorial found here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) but do not see this generated interface class mentioned anywhere. I attempted to call the webservice just like the tutorial says, but I am getting an error such as "The endpoint reference (EPR) for the operation not found is "http://mydefaulturi.com" and the WSA action ="

The generated interface has all of the methods the webservice supports as well as some annotations such as `@WebMethod`, `@WebResult`, `@RequestWrapper` & `@ResponseWrapper`. I suspect these annotations are required at the client end when making the request, but I am not using this interface.

Answer (score 0):

**I followed the Springboot tutorial found here but do not see this generated interface class mentioned anywhere.**

Below line in [Springboot tutorial found here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/), uses WSDL generated classes (GetQuote and GetQuoteResponse).

```
In this method, both the GetQuote and the GetQuoteResponse classes are derived from the WSDL and were generated in the JAXB generation process described in the previous step.
```

**Should I be using this interface?**

I think yes. In the example, the classes will be generated under `hello.wsdl` package, mentioned under `Generate domain objects based on a WSDL` section. It uses `jaxb2 plugin` and you are using `wsimport`. Both should work properly.

Hope this helps you.

(It will be helpful if you can provide some client and configuration classes similar to your implementation)